# Exclude a directory from custom ErrorDocuments

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Currently I have a few ErrorDocuments in my .htaccess (which is located in the www/site directory) like  `ErrorDocument 404 /site/error`, which work.

However, there is one directory in this site dir which should not have these custom error documents. So whenever an user tries to access /site/no_custom_errors/non_existing_file.png, I should get the default Apache error page and not my custom error.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your apache config for that directory can change it, or if "AllowOverride FileInfo" (see: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) is active for that site or directory, then an .htaccess file in that directory will work containing:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /site/otherErrorDoc
```

see:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument

Alternatively, it could be done in a <directory> directive in httpd.conf or in a virtual host like so:

```
<Directory path/to/special/directory>
    ErrorDocument 404 /site/otherErrorDoc
</Directory>
```

see:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory

Comment: Yeah, I thought about such a solution. Thing is, I'd prefer a if-not-then method, like `if directory is not "/site/no_custom_errors/" then [add error document] end`. Is there a possibility for that? If not, I'll stick to this solution.

Comment: Its really six of one/half dozen.  I believe you could pull that trick off with nginx pretty easily, but when it comes down to it, it is a trick.